# How to DM a user without them doing anything in the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a simple DM part of a bot and I've tried this method but it keeps giving me an error.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "Token Here"

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    me = await client.get_user_info('Snowflake ID Here')
    await client.send_message(me, "Message Here")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

It keeps giving me this error:

```
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

This method seems like the user needs to send a message but is there a way to do it without the user needing to send a message.

Comment: where did you copy the code? you may miss some imports?

Comment: what imports am i missing

Comment: where did you copy the code?

Comment: im running the bot in python directly on my computer so i did it from the python IDE @LeiYang

Comment: which discord.py version do you use?

Comment: how do i check the version of discord.py @Guddi

Comment: `import discord` \ `print(discord.__version__)` should work

Comment: I'm using discord.py version 1.7.3 also it wont send a dm. after i send a message it gives me an error:
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'
@Guddi

Comment: yea thats why I asked about the version, `client.send_message` doesnt work in 1.x u must use `user.send` or in your case `me.send("text")`

Comment: ok that's good but I'm still getting this error:
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'
@Guddi

Comment: its just `get_user`, i also wrote it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = disord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all()) # define client
# could also be commands.Bot()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    me = client.get_user(1234) # user id, must be int type
    await me.send("Message Here") # client.send(me, "message here") doesnt work in discord.py version 1.x

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, but you should provide textual explanations to better describe a solution the OP's issue and not just code.

Comment: after changing my code to be like that I got this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
@Guddi

Comment: ah he cant find the member without the `member Intent`, see [docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) - i will expand  the answer later if you have trouble with it - basically activate the intents in the dev portal and replace `.default()` with `.all()`

Comment: ive enabled the settings and changed it to all and its still giving me the same error @Guddi

Comment: did you use a valid user id?

Comment: yes i did. i followed discords guide on how to get user id's and it still says it has no attribute to send @Guddi

Comment: do you have a second `on_message` event in the same file? (there can be only one) - can you try to `print(me)` before `await me.send()`, what is the output?

Comment: i dont have a seccond on_message. everything is in the same file. i did print(me) and it came up as none @Guddi

Comment: do you have at least one shared server with the bot?

Comment: no. the bot is only on one server. @Guddi

Comment: yea than thats the problem, join that server and it will work ;)

Comment: oh you meant that. yes I'm in the same server as the bot and so is the person im trying to dm

Answer (score 0):

**Client Example**

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client): # defineding client
    async def on_ready(self):   # event
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message): # event
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        you = self.get_user(1234)
        await you.create_dm() # go to DM
        await you.send("Message Here") 


client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

**Bot Example**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>') # defineding client

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as', bot.user)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    you = bot.get_user(1234) 
    await you.create_dm() # go to DM
    await you.send("Message Here")


bot.run('token')
```

Comment: i used your example and it gave me this error:
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) @Delta

Comment: I'm using client @Delta

Comment: what's you'r dpy version? My version is `1.7.3`.

Comment: i am also running that version @Delta

Comment: `Logged on as Cute Bot#8006` idk, sorry